# Microsoft test ui automation bug on tabControl

Tags: testing, user-interface, automation

There is a bug on test ui automation that it is not able to recognize an element inside a tabControl on Visual Studio 2010

Somebody knows if it is already fixed on VS2012 or if there is a workaround on it??

I will appreciate your answers